# Code jumps back to button from previous form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

This is driving me crazy.  I am calling a form from a button_click on a menu screen.  Midway through the form_load on Form2, it is re-calling the button_click from the menu screen and not completing the form_load.  It always happens on the execute_reader from the 2nd combobox.

I've tried commenting out the whole chunk of code for the 2nd combobox and the form_load completes BUT if I then close that form and click the button on the menu screen again, it re-calls the same button_click but just after adapter.Fill(table).

Code from frmMenu

```
Private Sub btnManageEquipment_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles_ btnManageEquipment.Click
    frmManageEquipment2.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Code from frmManageEquipment2_Load

```
    Private Sub frmManageEquipment2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    strString = "Select * from equipment"
    adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(strString, conn)
    Dim commandBuilder As New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    adapter.Fill(table)
    bindEquipment.DataSource = table
    navEquipment.BindingSource = bindEquipment


    Me.txtEqName.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_Name", True))
    Me.cboArea.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_area", True))
    Me.cboEqSubarea.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_subarea", True))
    'Me.cboEqType.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_type", True))
    'Me.txtMarca.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_marca", True))
    'Me.txtModel.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_model", True))
    'Me.txtCapacity.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_capacity", True))
    'Me.txtSerieEquipe.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_SerieEquipe", True))
    'Me.txtSerieMotor.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_SerieMotor", True))
    'Me.txtEngineMarca.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_EngineMarka", True))
    'Me.txtEngineModel.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_EngineModel", True))
    'Me.txtAirFilter.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_AirFilter", True))
    'Me.txtTorqueConversion.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_TorqueConversion", True))
    'Me.txtTransmission.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_Transmission", True))
    'Me.txtAxle.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_Axle", True))
    'Me.txtBrakes.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_Brakes", True))
    'Me.txtStarterElecSystem.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_StarterElectSystem", True))
    'Me.txtTireSize.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_TireSize", True))
    'Me.txtFireSupprSystem.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_FireSupprSystem", True))
    'Me.txtCost.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_cost", True))
    'Me.txtPurchaseDate.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_PurchaseDate", True))
    'Me.txtLifeExpectance.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_LifeExpectancy", True))
    'Me.txtSellPrice.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_SellPrice", True))
    'Me.dtpSellDate.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_SellDate", True))
    ''Me.txtEqID.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_ID", True))
    'Me.txtEqID.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.bindEquipment, "Eq_ID", True))

    cboArea.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append
    strSQLArea = "Select distinct(eq_Area) from Equipment order by eq_Area"
    sqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQLArea, conn)
    Dim readerArea As MySqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    While readerArea.Read()
        cboArea.Items.Add(readerArea.GetString(0))
    End While
    cboArea.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append
    cboArea.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems


    cboEqSubarea.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append
     strSQLSubArea = "Select distinct(eq_SubArea) from Equipment order by eq_SubArea"
    sqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQLSubArea, conn)
    Dim readerSubArea As MySqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
'*****This is where it kicks back to the button click from the menu screen*******
   While readerSubArea.Read()
        cboEqSubarea.Items.Add(readerSubArea.GetString(0))
    End While
    cboEqSubarea.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append
    cboEqSubarea.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems

End Sub
```

*****I've changed how I handle this completely but am still having the same problem.  Now I am using a data adapter and binding my text boxes in their property fields.  I really want to use the autocomplete feature

```
Private Sub frmManageEquipment2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'AssetmgtDataSet.equipment' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.EquipmentTableAdapter.Fill(Me.AssetmgtDataSet.equipment)



    strSQL = "Select distinct(eq_Area) from Equipment order by eq_Area"
    txtArea.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    txtArea.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    sqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
    Dim readerArea As MySqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader
    Dim sStringCollArea As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    While readerArea.Read()
        sStringCollArea.AddRange(New String() {readerArea(0)})
    End While
    readerArea.Close()
    txtArea.AutoCompleteCustomSource = sStringCollArea


    strSQL = "Select distinct(eq_SubArea) from Equipment order by eq_SubArea"
    txtSubarea.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    txtSubarea.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    sqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
    Dim readerSubArea As MySqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader
    Dim sStringCollSubArea As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    While readerSubArea.Read()
****'This is where it goes back to the menu screen now****
        sStringCollSubArea.AddRange(New String() {readerSubArea(0)})
    End While
    readerSubArea.Close()
    txtSubarea.AutoCompleteCustomSource = sStringCollSubArea

End Sub
```

Comment: No simple explanation.  Except that it is clear that it takes a while before this form will be visible.  The user will get impatient and bang on the button repeatedly.  Those clicks gather up in the input queue and will execute later.  Create a responsive UI to avoid this failure mode, BackgroundWorker is the canonical approach.  Get a better answer by explaining what "kick back" might mean and how you know it is misbehaving.

Comment: You should at least call readerArea.Close() before opening readerSubArea, it may be crashing on trying to open a new data reader on the same command.

Comment: I added the readerArea.Close() and it actually gets a little bit further (to the cboEqSubarea.Items.Add(readerSubArea.GetString(0))" before going back to the menu form.  What is strange to me is that it doesnt generate an error.

Comment: Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?  I want it to run as fast and efficiently as possible.

Comment: I've uncommented out my list of databindings one by one and after the 10th one it craps out to the menu form.  I guess I'm overloading something.  Please help.  Its been years since I've been coding and I appreciate the help of this community.

Comment: Look in the Visual Studio Output window for a "first chance" exception message.

Comment: Thanks, Hans.  I hadnt even realized that was there.  Lets see what I can find.

Comment: I've rewritten everything and been keeping an eye on the output window.  I'm not sure how but the issue seems to have gone away for now.

Comment: @DebbieSegalWilliamson Did you ever get this to work? Looking at the code, it doesn't look like your culprit is here. It's probably in the event handlers of your other form related stuff. Also, there are probably multiple threads running. I would bring up the debugger to see what's going on. Open the threads window to see where all your threads are. Maybe freeze a few so you can debug them one at a time.

Comment: I think that this was many things.  I've moved some of the code into other places and cleaned things up a lot and the issue seems to have gone away.  I dont have time to really dig deep but I really appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the sql stuff on a seperate thread. Then start the thread from form_load. This should solve the problem.Putting heavy calculations/DBMS codes etc on UI thread  is not a good programming practice. It creates problems with both UI and calculation.

Answer (score 0):

do not call from directly create instance of it first

```
Dim nWindow As New frmManageEquipment2()
nWindow.Show()
```

write your coding in Shown event not in Load event